# make alias for all user on debian

Tags: debian, vps

hello please help me in this problem

I login to my VPS using root as the username

and I type

```
alias mycmd='ls'
```

when I accessing it in command line it works but when I type

```
sudo mycmd
```

it says sudo: reluser: command not found

how can i fix this things

Comment: could you please clarify? do you want all users to have the alias available as part of their alias or the issue is with running sudo over an alias?

Comment: yes i want my alias available as their alias

Comment: check https://askubuntu.com/a/22043/283843;

Answer (score 0):

you can create a script with your alias inside and put it in `/etc/profile.d/`

example:
`vi /etc/profile.d/00_alias.sh`

Inside it put the the following:

```
#!/bin/bash    
alias mycmd='ls'
```